# How to make `company-go` suggest completions from my own code?

Tags: company-mode, golang

My emacs go-lang setup is more or less the same as https://lupan.pl/dotemacs/.

I get suggestions from company-go for standard library (like fmt for example), but I don't get any suggestions from my own packages (that I am writing currently) whose sources reside in the same GOPATH.

Adding some explanation.  The following is roughly how my code is organised.

My code is in

```
$GOPATH/src/mydomain.tld/myname/myproject/core/
$GOPATH/src/mydomain.tld/myname/myproject/feature1/
$GOPATH/src/mydomain.tld/myname/myproject/main.go
```

In main.go, I import code like so:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "mydomain.tld/myname/myproject/core/"
    "mydomain.tld/myname/myproject/feature1/"
)

func main() {
      // I expect to get a list of functions inside feature1 package, or at least a list of types in it. 
       variable1 := feature1.    

}
```

Any idea can be done to make company-go suggest completions from my own code ? Once again, I get suggestions from standard library packages just fine.

I use emacs-27 on FreeBSD-13.0 (GhostBSD 19.2), go 1.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies, some digging around with gocode -s -debug revealed that it couldn't resolve the import paths "mydomain.tld/myname/myproject/core/"

I then realised that I should be doing

"go install ./..." so that the all the code in "mydomain.tld/myname/myproject" will be recursively built and installed to $GOPATH/pkg.

I am new to Golang, and I realise this was a n00b question now.

Comment: I think this makes sense for other n00bs like me who'd wnat an emacs setup for Golang.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. You can configure gocode to rebuild packages automatically using: gocode set autobuild true

Answer (score 1):

If you use flycheck, set

```
(setq flycheck-go-build-install-deps t)
```

This will install your dependencies automatically.
More details in flycheck docs: https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/languages.html#go